# API Versioning along with middle tier code versioning

Tags: .net, versioning

We have .Net based web application, which has app.net web api services, middle tire with (3 layers) and database.
We understand how to do versioning of service layer, and we have chosen to include version number as part of the rest URL 
Ex: https://domainname/_api/v1.0/users/123 
       https://domainname/_api/v2.0/users/123

We have middle tier with 3 layers.

We are expecting the code changes to happen in all layers of middle tier code. Except deleting existing methods, classes, properties, updating signature of existing methods all other kinds modifications will be there for the code.
What we need to understand is best practices followed (or reference to some case studies) to version middle tier code base so that version1 of the service calls to version1 of the code base and version 2 of the service calls to version 2 of the code base.